# Angular 7 service response to component mapping or interpolation

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing a website with Angular 7 and bootstrap 4 and I am new to angular. I calling a asp.net Web API to retrieve a business information. This is returning the data correctly. My angular project's setup is like this, I have two folders one for models and another for services under /src/app and respective folders for each component. Please see the code of all the parts

I tried logging the response in different places. It logs the object but not the properties, property values are undefined.

```
app.module.ts
*******************************************************************
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './supplier/dashboard.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
import { SupplierService } from './services/supplier.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [SupplierService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
**************************************************************************
supplier.service.ts
**************************************************************************
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IBusiness } from './../models/business.model';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable ({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SupplierService {

  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient){

  }

  getSupplier(id: number): Observable<IBusiness> {
    return this._httpClient.get<IBusiness>('http://localhost:55970/api/supplier/' + id);   

  }
}
******************************************************************************
business.model.ts ======= I tried to make use of class and Interface, both approach didn't work
******************************************************************************
export interface IBusiness {
   Id: number;
  Record_Number: string;
  Business_Name: string;
 }

OR

export class Business {

   constructor(public Id: number, public Record_number: string, public Business_Name: string) {

    } 
}

******************************************************************************
business.component.ts
******************************************************************************
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SupplierService } from '../services/supplier.service';
import { IBusiness } from '../models/business.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  //templateUrl: './business.component.html',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{ name }} {{ supplier.Record_Number}}</h1>`,  ------> name property value is displayed but not supplier property
  styleUrls: ['./business.component.css']
})
export class BusinessComponent implements OnInit {
  supplier: IBusiness;
  name: string

  constructor(public supplierService: SupplierService) {
    this.name = "Test Name";
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.supplierService.getSupplier(1001).subscribe((result: IBusiness) => {
console.log(result); ------>>>>>> i see this in console

//{
//<Record_Number>k__BackingField: "00230367CM"
//}
console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); ------>>>>>> i see this in console
//{
//"<Record_Number>k__BackingField":"00230367CM"
//}

      console.log(result.Record_Number);
      console.log(result); ----->>> this logs the object with all the db values. But property values are not mapped to the angular object
      this.supplier = result;
      console.log(this.supplier.Record_Number);
      console.log(result.Record_Number);
    });

  }

}
******************************************************************************
business.component.html
******************************************************************************
<div class="container" style="height:50%">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h6>{{ supplier.Business_Name }}</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text"> RecordNumber: {{ supplier.Record_Number }} </div>
              <div class="card-text"> Name: {{ supplier.Business_Name }} </div>                  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
******************************************************************************
```

Comment: Your template could break as you are referencing supplier in your template(in this case you should see and error message) and supplier could be still undefined as the service call could take some time. Can you add a "?" behind supplier? So it looks like {{supplier?.Record_number}}. Its called the safe navigation operator(https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)

Comment: i tried this {{supplier?.Record_number}}, still undefined

Comment: Can you make sure you are getting back JSON in your subscribe?

Comment: I saw this in watch typeof(result): "object". It says it is an object. How can i get json. I thought angular 7 httpclient by default returns json, but mine is saying object.

Comment: edited the post to include some console logging in the subscribe method 
console.log(result); ------>>>>>> i see this in console
      
//{
//<Record_Number>k__BackingField: "00230367CM"
//}
console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); ------>>>>>> i see this in console
//{
//"<Record_Number>k__BackingField":"00230367CM"
//}

Comment: then how can i get the angular class object to bind the values in html? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please show me how?

Comment: `this logs the object with all the db values`, so **what** are the values? We cannot help if we don't know how your data looks like that you are receiving ;)

Comment: After matching the angular object to the C# object, i see the result for properties. But i have a question, should the two objects match for the angular subscribe method to serialize the C# object to json data? The C# object is generic and has lot more properties than this angular app requires coz angular app is new front end app for the established REST web api. I thought i could just have the properties needed for this angular app, is my assumption wrong?

Comment: If you want just some properties, you need to tell that you just want some properties, angular cannot automagically know what data you want. Either the data needs to match your interface, or you have to pick the data you want from the response to make it match your interface.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the server response does not correctly implement IBusiness interface.
Are the properties on IBusiness the same name as the object properties from the server response?

Remember C# properties like `Record_Number` is parsed on JSON files as `record_Number`

Comment: Yes, the C# property names match the angular class/interface. I even checked their camel casing. What else could be going wrong. I see the result object with all the values

Comment: After matching the angular object to the C# object, i see the result for properties. But i have a question, should the two objects match for the angular subscribe method to serialize the C# object to json data? The C# object is generic and has lot more properties than this angular app requires coz angular app is new front end app for the established REST web api. I thought i could just have the properties needed for this angular app, is my assumption wrong?

Comment: This is not an angular thing, but more a Typescript issue. When you use _httpService, you provide an interface that the JSON result **must** implement. So Typescript will get the json and try to match its properties to the given interface. If you only need *some* properties, leave only those on the interface IBusiness. Do i make myself clear? :)

Answer (score 0):

We have gathered from comments that you are getting a lot more properties from your response, also some that don't seem to match your interface. Then you need to tell Angular, which properties you want and how to map them. Like so:

```ts
getSupplier(id: number): Observable<IBusiness> {
  return this._httpClient.get<IBusiness>('...').pipe(
    map(x => x.map(y => <IBusiness>{Id: y.prop, Record_Number: y.prop, Business_Name: y.prop}))
  )  
}
```

**where `prop` in the above is the properties from the response that you want to map to the corresponding properties in your interface**.